# Concatinating Views in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-blade

I'm studying Laravel, and I want to know how to concatinate multiple views together.

I've looked through the documentation on [laravel.com](http://www.laravel.com) and can't find the section that tells me how to concatinate views.

I've solved the problem like this (*in my controller*):

```
public function showPage() {
    return View::make('header') . View::make('content') . View::make('footer');
}
```

But surely there is a better/correct way... I would appreciate any help.

Comment: A view has to be rendered so Laravel can not render views in the way you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can load do something like this

```
public function showPage() {
    return View::make('page');
}
```

And in your `page.blade.php`:

```
@include('header')
@include('content')
@include('footer')
```

But actually it would be better to have this structure.

`layout.blade.php`:

```
@include('header')

@yield('content')

@include('footer')
```

`page.blade.php`:

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')
     HTML of content here...
@stop
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it's surely better than my approach.
But this still seems to be **coupled**... Is there no better way, or am I asking the wrong question?
Is concatinating the views the best way to show the components in a decoupled way?

Comment: What do you mean by coupled?

Comment: @ArturGrigio, first of all laravel treat views like objects - they had inheritance, can be extended, can be included. the workflow of laravel view is to put all the same code in the parent while the childs modifies (replace or add) the parent component. **ps** if you did want to make some part of your `included` element modifiable, just pass them as a parameter - you could always `@include($someView)`.

Comment: You can also inject variables to sub-views by passing them as an associative array as the second parameter.

Comment: @Tezla Thank you for the clarification :)